# javascript replace with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to use javascript replace with regex in this situation?

```
<div id="content" style="left: 200px">
=><div id="content" style="left: -200px">

var num = $('#content').attr('style');
alert(num.replace.replace('/[0-9]+/g','-\\$1'));


<div id="content" style="left: -200px">
=><div id="content" style="left: 200px">

var num = $('#content').attr('style');
alert(num.replace.replace('/-[0-9]+/g','\\$1'));
```

my code seems not work, need a help. thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$&` to signify the matched value in the 2nd argument.  This is a JavaScript feature of `.replace` and not a feature of regular expressions.

```
var x = "left: 200px".replace(/\d+/,'-$&')
// x == "left: -200px"
```

Answer (score 1):

`$1` refers to the first capture group - of which you have none. As John says you can use `$&` to refer to the entire match.

To use `$1` you would need to put `()` around your match to create the capture group `/([0-9]+)/g`

Comment: I had no idea you can use capture groups.  That is insanely useful.

Comment: I on the other hand only discovered `$&` a few hours ago ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this :

```
$('#content').css('left', function (i, value) {
    return -parseInt(value);
});
```

Here is a demo (click the red box) : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/s6M43/.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` also takes a function so, you can do something like

```
var str = '<div id="content" style="left: 200px"> => <div id="content" style="left: -200px">';
str.replace(/(-?)([0-9]+)/g, function(match, sign, px) { return '-' == sign ? px : '-' + px })
//'<div id="content" style="left: -200px"> => <div id="content" style="left: 200px">'
```